# Prevent TFS from erroneously duplicating lines

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, version-control

I have found an Issue where TFS duplicates lines of source when merging two files.
I have been able to reliably reproduce the issue with the following actions.

1) Commit the following file to a TFS repository

```
Line1
```

(Please note that there are trailing tabs on that line)

2) Branch that file to a branch KeepTabs
3) Edit the file and commit so it is as below

```
Line1      
This is Line2
```

(Please note that there is a equal number of tabs at the end of line1 as in og file).

4) Branch the Original File to a branch LoseTabs
5) Edit the file and commit so it is as below

```
Line1
LineALPHA Line1 Doesn't have tabs
```

(Please note that the tabs trailing Line1 are removed)

6) Merge the LoseTabs file to the og trunk. Get no conflicts and file is as expected.

7) Merge the KeepTabs file to the og trunk. A conflict will occur. Note that Line1 With tabs is considered a seperate and distinct line from Line1 With no tabs... note how Line1 is duplicated from OG File to exist in newly merged file while neither branch nor original contained Line 1 multiple times.

[Visual of merge results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2YD6.png)

It is important to us that particular files are able to edited simultaneously by multiple users. Often these changes are of a form where there are a set of commented out lines that developers either copy->paste->Uncomment->Edit for purpose->done... or the developer types the edit they would have copy/pasted->done. And that is where the issue is. The users that copy paste may copy only to the last ascii character, or they may copy past the whole line. The users that Type in the edit directly do not see the extra whitespace.  I don't want to specify that users MUST copy/paste. I also don't want to specify that users CANNOT copy paste.

I also don't want to specify that files must have trailing whitespace removed. 1) Because there are tons of files and doing that would be cumbersome. 2) Because of the tons of files each file has hundreds of lines any of which may or may not have trailing white space within a literal string that breaks multiple lines. 3) Removing it once doesn't prevent trailing white space from appearing again on accident.

Also, merging the changes from the trunk to the branch with the changes to be applied to the trunk causes the same line duplication issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna say it's by design. that's the expected behavior during resolve merge conflicts.

Duplicating lines is caused by selecting both **Source** and **Target** lines. Since they have conflicts, by default it will keep both **Source** and **Target** lines in the result if you select both of them, then edit in result to accept the merge.

Please see [Resolve merge conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/merging?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio#resolve-merge-conflicts-1) for details.

- > This will bring up a list of files with conflicts. Selecting a file
  >   lets you accept the changes in the source branch you are merging from
  >   with the **Take Source** button or accept the changes in the branch you
  >   are merging into using **Keep Target**. You can manually merge changes by
  >   selecting **Merge**, then entering the changes directly into the merge
  >   tool specified in your Git settings.
- > Use the checkboxes next to the lines modified to select between remote
  >   and local changes entirely, or edit the results directly in the Result
  >   editor under the **Source** and **Target** editor in the diff view.
- > When done
  >   making changes, click **Accept Merge** . Repeat this for all conflicting
  >   files.

Comment: @Eightvo Is that answered your question? any update?